# Way to extract gzip files from variable

Tags: python, python-requests, gzip

I ran into problem after downloading mnist file,

`mnist.pkl.gz`
It is now saved in content

```
content =requests.get('http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz').content
```

Now I dont want to extract pkl file in folder, instead load all training and testing files inside variable. I came to know gzip which is not possible to do this inside variable.
Any idea guys?

Comment: I don't believe that gzip can extract compressed data into multiple files. Try saving your data to a file and using [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) instead.

Comment: What is *in* the gz file? Is it just a ``pickle`` dump, or something else?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yea it is pickle, I had used 
`pickle.load(gzip.open('/content/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb'), encoding="latin-1")` to load from downloaded file, that what i dont want to.